# How to use ibeacon when application in background and iphone reboot

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, estimote

So i'm developing the iOS app with objective c language. problem is with the ibeacon notification with iPhone.

So basically phone is monitoring entry and exit of beacon with the specific UUID and major minor. Its working good when the app is in the foreground and also when the app is in the background then also receiving enter and exit beacon region notification.

But the problem is when app is in background and phone is locked, then notification is not received. but when i unlock the phone, it's automatically received the notification.

Can you guys please anyone suggest me the solution regarding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nothing special is needed to detect beacons in the background after reboot** using CoreLocation monitoring APIs.  If detections work without a reboot they should work with one.

The important thing to know about the bootup process on iOS is that **it can take several minutes after reboot before CoreLocation is fully initialized** and responding to Bluetooth LE beacons.  When testing after a reboot, be extra patient.  The fact that illuminating the display accelerates this process does not change that this is true.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung.
One more confusion is if my app is force fully killed from device when my device is enter from ibeacon region but notification is not appear.

Comment: If you are already in the region when you kill the app, then you probably will not get a new entry notification until the phone leaves the region and re-enters.